# My pop os terminal shows "script engine for language js can not be found" everytime i open it.How do i fix it?

Tags: java, bash, shell, terminal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seneN.png)
I have openjdk 19 installed but everytime it shows the error ,pls anyone tell me how do i get rid of it

I tried uninstalling java and installing it again but it shows the same error everytime. uninstalling java and reinstlling other version shows nashorn engine error.

Comment: "js" is not Java. It's javascript. I don't think (un)installing openjdk is going to make a difference.

Comment: but this only shows when java is installed if unistalled it will not show

Comment: maybe check your `.bashrc` for some command that tries to use Nashorn?

Comment: this is written in it
export JAVA_HOME="$(jrunscript -e 'java.lang.System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.home"));')"

Comment: The `jrunscript` command is exactly the reason of your error. The JavaScript support was dropped in Java/OpenJDK version 15 (if I remember correctly)